# NSURLConnection and URL Downloading Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection

If I am implementing NSURLConnection delegate methods in the AppDelegate and I am calling them from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, then `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will execute before the delegate methods.

Since `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` adds the navigation controller or tab bar controller or whatever view to the main window and display, where would I put the methods below if I need NSURLConnection to finish its download before the first view launches?

```
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Basically, I need to download a timestamp online and according to that timestamp, I will either clear and re-download my core data database and then display the view, or I will just display the view. That is why I need NSURLConnection to finish its execution before the view is loaded.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below line in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Till that you can show splash screen. Default.png

Comment: Terrible idea. If the user runs on EDGE, they will think that the app is unresponsive.

Comment: btw, you can inform user by having progress bar by getting content size from didReceiveResponse delegate method, so it is not terrible idea...

Comment: That was just suggestion you can do anything while you load your data. Like showing loading Indicator, Progress view etc. Something you should think by your own mind. We can not feed you everything..

Comment: Never asked you to feed me anything - I actually thought about it a lot more than you, and tried different implementations. I was trying to see if anyone has any different suggestions, or has a different point of view.

Comment: so did you try applying progressbar, to show user how many bytes are you getting from connection? this way user will come to know, that something is in progress and will wait until it is 100% responded...

Comment: Then you should mentioned that in question that I tried bla bla bla and any other suggestion. You just said where should I put this 2 lines.

Comment: @Jignesh Brahmkhatri yes I did.. But I had a problem with my main view would launch twice, upon finishing `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then at the end of `connectionDidFinishLoading`.

Comment: but do not code anything in application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you can addSubview in window only in connectionDidFinishLoading or if connectionDidFailWithError methods

Answer (score 1):

I would display what i have while downloading asynchronously. The associated callback methods can update the model (database). If that happens update the view. Letting the user sit and wait while downloading stuff is not nice.